# Newly generated empty file does not overlap the old in shell?

Tags: shell

Forgive me if this is a silly question, but I noticed that if I used a command to generate an 0 B file, and later run the same command, then my server does not seem to update me with a new file - at least not judging by the modification time.

For example, I do

```
awk '$1 == "aaa"' ori.txt  > test.txt
```

where ori.txt does not have aaa, and thus test.txt is empty. If I later run this line again, I was not able to get a newly dated test.txt (checked on FileZilla and "date -r")

Not that this matters that much, but I want to confirm I did not miss something here. Thank you very much.

Comment: What is the underlying file system? Is it NFS? What are the mount options (run `mount` without arguments)? Did you give the file system some time to write meta-data (30s)?

Answer (score 0):

The file is not created by `awk`, but by the shell (which, according to your *shell* tag, should be Posix shell). You could simplify your program to

```
: >test.txt
```

Everytime you run this, an empty test.txt is freshly created. I suggest that you verify this by placing `ls -l` after this command and inspect its output, for instance

```
outfile=test.txt 
: >$outfile
ls -l $outfile | tee timestamp.txt
```